# How to set consent cookie on google domain in a HTTP request?

Tags: rest, http

At the moment I’m just prototyping (scraping google maps favourite list data) using VSCode REST Client extension, but as far as I can tell it should be fully featured.

The request is simple, I want the HTML content of the URL, but I get stopped by the mandated cookie consent redirect.

As far as I‘ve been able to investigate, I should be able to

```
GET URL HTTP/1.1
Set-Cookie: CONSENT=YES+
```

But this still redirects to the consent page.

Am I missing some header, or other cookie, or is there any other way to bypass the consent page and get to the desired page.

I think the main issue is that there’s both a cookie redirect occurring and the URL comes in different shortened forms depending on where you share it from (app vs desktop).  I want a generic solution as I need the ultimate application to be able to receive URL’s in any of google’s formats.

More information and results available on request, I don’t want to bog down the post with possibly unnecessary details as I’m hoping there’s a very simple set cookie solution I’m
missing here that works on google domain regardless of application.

Comment: simply request in SwiftUI works exactly as intended however the application i'm making is more much usable as a web app so I'd prefer to redesign in javascript.  but the concept is obviously possible as swift manages it